# $_POST only partially containing data submitted

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am creating a form for some data input, with a button that adds a table row for each day every time there is a new Job

```
<h3>Monday</h3>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <form name="add_name" id="add_name" action="action.php" method="post">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamic_field_mon">
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Site Job No</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Work Undertaken</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Start Work</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Finish Work</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Lunch</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Total Hours</strong></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="add_mon" id="add_mon" class="btn btn-primary">Add Job</button></td>  
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Tuesday</h3>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-group">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dynamic_field_tue">
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Site Job No</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Work Undertaken</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Start Work</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Finish Work</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Lunch</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Total Hours</strong></td>
                <td><button type="button" name="add_tue" id="add_tue" class="btn btn-primary">Add Job</button></td>  
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This continues until Sunday, where after Sunday I have added the following:

```
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Timesheet">
</form>
```

The Javascript for the above adds the fields correctly for each day, and I can add and remove the fields as is, however, the required input for Tuesday isn't working, and when I submit the form, only the information for Monday is submitted and the submit button, when I `var_dump($_POST)`

Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var i = 1;

    $("#add_mon").click(function(){
      i++;
      $('#dynamic_field_mon').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="mon_jobno[]" placeholder="Site Job No" class="form-control name_list" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="mon_description[]" placeholder="List A Description Of Work Undertaken" class="form-control name_email" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="mon_startwork[]" placeholder="Start Work" class="form-control name_email" minlength="4" maxlength="5" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="mon_finishwork[]" placeholder="Finish Work" class="form-control name_email" minlength="4" maxlength="5" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="mon_lunch[]" placeholder="Lunch" class="form-control name_email" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="mon_totalhours[]" placeholder="Total Hours" class="form-control name_email" required/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
    });

    $("#add_tue").click(function(){
      i++;
      $('#dynamic_field_tue').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="tue_jobno[]" placeholder="Site Job No" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><input type="text" name="tue_description[]" placeholder="List A Description Of Work Undertaken" class="form-control name_email" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="tue_startwork[]" placeholder="Start Work" class="form-control name_email" minlength="4" maxlength="5" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="tue_finishwork[]" placeholder="Finish Work" class="form-control name_email" minlength="4" maxlength="5" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="tue_lunch[]" placeholder="Lunch" class="form-control name_email" required/></td><td><input type="text" name="tue_totalhours[]" placeholder="Total Hours" class="form-control name_email" required/></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
    });

$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
});
  });
```

Comment: You can only submit one `<form>` at a time. If you want to send all information, then you should wrap all fields in a single form.

Comment: I have done this, I will edit my question to show

Comment: Place your `<form>` before Monday, place `</form>` after Sunday.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I moved the Form tags before Monday and closed it after Sunday and still only Monday's information is posted after being submitted

Comment: Sorry I was editing a cached version of the file, did this and it now works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your form tag is opened in Monday section (and not closed ?), so it's not enclose all yours inputs.

And, if you click submit button inside form, it will execute this form and not other if you have multiple forms on your page.

Comment: Apologies, have edited my question to show more of the form including the closing tags